# bash - reuse code snippet in different function definitions

Tags: bash, function, code-reuse

Some of my utils functions often share the exact same initial code, that allows the function to be called with an argument or piped input:

```
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
RESET=$(tput sgr0)

# -----------

function yellow {
  local arg
  if (( "$#" == 0 )); then
      IFS= read -r arg
      set -- "$arg"
  fi
  echo "${YELLOW}$1${RESET}"
}
function red {
  local arg
  if (( "$#" == 0 )); then
      IFS= read -r arg
      set -- "$arg"
  fi
  echo "${RED}$1${RESET}"
}
```

Is there a technique that allows me to "reuse" or somehow source the identical portion of code  into the function definition?
In my example this would be:

```
local arg
if (( "$#" == 0 )); then
  IFS= read -r arg     
  set -- "$arg"
fi
```

Comment: `source script_name.sh` or just `. script_name.sh` but be careful, script will be executed while sourcing

Comment: wow, did not know you could source random snippet of code. thanks, it works. Now I have to wrap my head around  the possible side effects of the fact that the script is executed while sourcing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can make this much shorter with:

```sh
set -- "${1:-$(cat)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

To partial source vars and/or functions from some script use this method:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

test=123
mess() { echo ok; }
# Vars and functions ends here ^^
[[ $1 =~ source ]] && return
mess
```

Then souce it like this:

```
. ./test source
```